# Filehandle issue with system call in C

Tags: c, perl, unix, filehandle, file-descriptor

In my C program I make a system call that executes the 'cat' UNIX command, something like this.

```
sprintf(command, "cat %s", filename);
fprintf(stderr, "Executing command: '%s'\n", command);
system(command);
```

When I compile and run the program, the command is not executed properly. instead I get the following error.

```
Executing command: 'cat temp.txt'
cat: stdout: Bad file descriptor
```

My question is two-fold.

1. Why is this code not working correctly, and how can I fix it?
2. When I try something like `perl -e 'system("cat temp.txt")'` on the command line, it works as expected. What is the difference between how Perl deals with file handles and how C deals with them?

Thanks!

**Update**: Thanks to the comments, I figured out the problem pretty quickly. I had accidentally closed stdout earlier in the program, which is why there was an error when the `cat` program tried to print to stdout. So it looks like there is no difference between how C and Perl deal with file handles: the  following command generates the exact same error.

```
$ perl -e 'close(STDOUT); system("cat temp.txt")'
cat: stdout: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: I just wonder, why it's not: Executing command: 'cat temp.txt'

Comment: Anything done with `stdout`? Perhaps it is closed prior to the call?

Comment: do you perhaps have stdout closed?

Comment: How are you running the program?  It's possible that you may have closed stdout (e.g. if you forked)

Comment: Did you close `stdout` from some reason?

Comment: @FooBah: forking would not close stdout.

Comment: Can you please try sprintf(command, "cat %s > /dev/stdout", filename);

Comment: Ok, that was it. I accidentally closed stdout before the command was executed.

Comment: First to post as an answer gets the accept!

Comment: Ah.. And I was in preparation of nice answer...

Comment: @Andrejs Sorry, turns out it was a simple mistake, I just didn't recognize the warning message.

Comment: @Hasturkun sometimes people explicitly close stderr.  One example circumstance under which a person may close stderr is when a process is forked. I didnt mean to imply forking automatically closes stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your default `stdout` file descriptor is not there. `stdout` is closed.